# Configuring SVN server on Apache on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, http, svn, webdav

I'm trying to access an existing Subversion server over HTTP. My `dav_svn.conf` file looks like:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /home/svn/repos
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Access"
    AuthUserFile /home/svn/passwdfile
    Require valid-user
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/svn/accessfile
</Location>
```

But when I'm trying to access "some-site/svn", I'm getting the following error:

> The requested URL /svn/ was not found on this server.

The Apache error log shows "file does not exist: /var/www/svn"

How do I resolve this?

Comment: This should be moved to super user

Comment: It sounds like you never told Apache about your dav_svn.conf - Did you load the module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this:

```
a2enmod dav_svn
service apache2 restart
```

as super user (`root`), e.g. `sudo a2enmod dav_svn && sudo service apache2 restart`.

This assumes that you are using the proper method (Debian+Ubuntu) of editing the two files:  `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.{conf,load}`, not some homebrew method.

Comment: Yep, that was ***exactly*** what was needed to make it work on a new installation on Raspberry Pi (Apache 2.4) - Debian-based like Ubuntu. (For an older installation on another Raspberry Pi, based on Apache 2.2, it had worked out of the box. The exact same installation procedure was used for both of them.)